# NSNotification userinfo keeps stacking when pushing buttons

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications, nsnotification

So I have two viewcontrollers, which are shown at the same time. The goal is the following: when I press the menu, it gives back an index. This will notify the other screen that it needs to update.

I am doing the following:

Controller A (the menu)

```
   func carbonTabSwipeNavigation(carbonTabSwipeNavigation: CarbonTabSwipeNavigation, didMoveAtIndex index: UInt) {
    //NSLog("Did move at index: %ld", index)
        //NSNotification to send data
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(NotificationNames.GetIndexCarbonKit, object: nil, userInfo: ["clickedIndex" : Int(index)])
}
```

Controller B (the receiver)

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(SearchResults.didReceiveNotification(_:)), name: NotificationNames.GetIndexCarbonKit, object: nil)
}


func didReceiveNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    let index:Dictionary<String,Int> = notification.userInfo as! Dictionary<String,Int>
    let messageFromNotification = index["clickedIndex"]
    print(" SearchResults now shows index: \(messageFromNotification)")
}
```

My issue is the following: the Dictionary in which I'm sending the index from A to B, keeps stacking. So if I press the menu multiple times, my output is the following:

```
 SearchResults now shows index: Optional(0)
 SearchResults now shows index: Optional(1)
 SearchResults now shows index: Optional(1)
 SearchResults now shows index: Optional(2)
 SearchResults now shows index: Optional(2)
 SearchResults now shows index: Optional(2)
 SearchResults now shows index: Optional(3)
 SearchResults now shows index: Optional(3)
 SearchResults now shows index: Optional(3)
 SearchResults now shows index: Optional(3)
 SearchResults now shows index: Optional(1)
 SearchResults now shows index: Optional(1)
 SearchResults now shows index: Optional(1)
 SearchResults now shows index: Optional(1)
 SearchResults now shows index: Optional(1)
```

How can I only get the last index? I don't need a stack of the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the correct answer myself. Apparently all I had to do was add the NotificationCenter to the ViewWillAppear, and remove it at the ViewWillDisappear. When I switch in the menu between the views (which is 4 times the same view) it only gives back one value.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(SearchResults.didReceiveNotification(_:)), name: NotificationNames.GetIndexCarbonKit, object: nil)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}

func didReceiveNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    let index:Dictionary<String,Int> = notification.userInfo as! Dictionary<String,Int>
    self.currentIndex = (index.first?.1)!
    print(currentIndex)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use it in `viewdidappear`! It is a method which is called more than once in a ViewController. Instead use it in `viewDidLoad` which is executed only **once** that is when the view controller is loaded.
 And you have to call it in the

```
func didReceiveNotification(notification: NSNotification)
```

And after the function use:

```
deinit {
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I changed it. still doesn't stop the dictionary from stacking though.

Comment: Check my edited answer. You shouldn't call it in viewDidLoad either.

Comment: I can't do that, since the `func didReceiveNotification` is called only after I added the observer. Hence the    `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(SearchResults.didReceiveNotification(_:))`

Comment: It doesn't matter too much **where** you add the observer as long as you also remove it at a matching point.  Put print statements where you add an observer and where you remove it.  Make sure they're balanced (a remove for every add).

Comment: You've to remove the observer. Check out my answer and try it.

Comment: @PhillipMills I can't remove it yet, since I always need to know what the user has pressed. The two viewcontrollers are both visible at the same time. I remove the NSNotification when the user actually leaves the screen.

Comment: You also can't add it more than once or you get exactly what you're complaining about.  `NSNotificationCenter` doesn't care that an object is already registered for a specific notification; it just blindly adds it again and calls it however many times it has been told.

Comment: @Dershowitz123 doing this solved my problem partly. Now the max number of stacks is 4 for some reason. Still not just the last though

Answer (score 0):

Is the dictionary actually stacking or is that just the console windows output? Try clearing the console window after each push of the menu button to see whats going on. The index is scoped to that function so once that function is done it disappears.

Comment: It's actually stacking. I cleaned the console after my 3rd push, and at the 4th I got  SearchResults now shows index: Optional(3)
 SearchResults now shows index: Optional(3)
 SearchResults now shows index: Optional(3)
 SearchResults now shows index: Optional(3)

Comment: The dictionary still only contains the one value but your firing the post notification multiple times. If you breakpoint the didReceiveNotification func I'm guessing its cycling several times for each button press. What does the code look like that does the post?

Comment: Added the code to the question. It's a function from CarbonKit, but if I check with NSLog, it only calls that index once

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the last clicked index just declare a variable in your class and set the index on that variable so you will get the last clicked index every time you retrieve it

```
func didReceiveNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    let index:Dictionary<String,Int> = notification.userInfo as! Dictionary<String,Int>
    self.messageFromNotification = index["clickedIndex"]
    print(" SearchResults now shows index: \(messageFromNotification)")
}
```